# Pika connecting using SSL with no certificate file

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to use pika to connect to RabbitMQ using SSL (self signed).

The problem is that the connect not failing if I do  not give the certificate file to pika.

This is my code:

```
import pika
import urllib

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters("amqps://guest:guest@172.16.120.130:25585"))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')

print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

And this is my rabbitmq.config:

```
{tcp_listeners, []},
{ssl_listeners, [25585]},
{ssl_options, [{cacertfile,           "/etc/rabbitmq/certs/cacert.pem"},
               {certfile,             "/etc/rabbitmq/certs/cert.pem"},
               {keyfile,              "/etc/rabbitmq/certs/key.pem"},
               {verify,               verify_peer},
               {versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1', 'tlsv1']},
               {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]},
```

I have disabled TCP connection and enabled the SSL, why is the connection not failing?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this configuration in the server: `{fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}`

Change it to : `{fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}`

It means *drop the connection if there is no certificate presented by Client*.

Comment: I don't want client authentication, i wnt that the client library (pika) will drop the connection if the certificate not valid

Comment: In that case, create the connection with the following parameters at client side: `pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host='172.16.120.130', port=25585, credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(user, password), ssl=True, ssl_options = {"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, "ca_certs": caCert}))`

Where `caCert` is the certificate file containing server certificate.

Comment: If you don't do that your client will ignore the server certificate validation. you need to tell your client to verify the server certificate with `ssl_options` in connection settings